# Why is !== "" is not equal to !== null

Tags: javascript, resharper

Recently in JavaScript i have picked up the habit of using

```
if(data !== "")
```

to check if the data is null || undefined || blank string.

When i try to use

```
if(data !== null)
   //work here
```

Resharper throws a horrible error at me saying that the

> "qualifier can be null or undefined"

[image]

I have added a jFiddle just to clarify : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzkUL/)

**My question is:** Is this a ReSharper error or is there something behind this ?

Comment: If you want to check for an `falsey` value, why not just use `if (data) {}`

Comment: the if(data) will not work correctly for older versions of IE, if data is undefined IE7 i believe will error up

Comment: @jfriend00 there's a slight difference for empty arrays `[] != "" -> false` but `!![] -> true`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - If you want to test for an empty array, then test for an empty array.  An empty array isn't a `falsey` value and testing for `!== ""` is no way to test for an empty array either as that doesn't distinguish between an empty array and a full array so I really don't get your point.  I wasn't saying that `if (data)` is equivalent to what the OP was using, just that it's probably a better way of testing a `truthy/falsey` value which is what it sounds like the OP actually wanted.

Comment: Perhaps the question needs more context.. data in this case is an object, is there no universal nullcheck for all objects, variable type and arrays ?

Comment: @jfriend00 agreed, I just thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @Pogrindis - please share a line of code where `if (data)` won't work in IE7 to test for a `truthy/falsey` value.  I think you're mistaken here.

Comment: `!== null` is not the same as `!== ""` because Null and String are two different data types, and you are using strict comparison. "Is there no universal null check for objects and arrays" null is null, it doesn't have anything to do with other data types/values. Based on the warning I would say you have to use `data != null`, which checks whether the value is not `null` and not `undefined`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, your habit is wrong. Using:

```
if(data !== "")
```

Will only check for an empty string. If `data` is `undefined` or `null`, the if block will still execute because `!==` checks for equality without performing any type conversions.

Secondly, ReSharper does not have an issue. It's trying to tell you that you may be making a mistake. `if(data !== null)` will only check against null. `undefined` and an empty string will still return true and cause the block to execute. ReSharper is warning you that you *may* be making a mistake (because rarely do you ever need to check for just `null`).

Just remember that `undefined !== null !== ""`. You could attempt several of the shortcuts that are being mentioned but if you really want your code to be thorough, just check all three. If you're worried about code being too long, move the check to a utility method:

```
function hasValue(var data) {
    return (data !== undefined) && (data !== null) && (data !== "");
}
```

Comment: Just to call back on this over the years. This is infact the right answer. And explained well. Taught me a lot about JS.

Answer (score 5):

In short, a `var` is `null` when it's not pointing anywhere.
In the other hand, a `var` equal to `""` is a defined var pointing to a variable which contains an empty string. That's essentially different.

**[EDIT]**
As @jfriend00 correctly points out, `null` is a specific value in javascript. The difference would be then that `null` is a different value than `""`, which is an empty string and therefor not null.

The correct value for a `var` which is not initialized is `undefined`.

Comment: Be very careful with your definiton of `null` here.  `null` is a specific value in javascript.  A variable ONLY contains `null` if it was specifically assigned that value.  A variable that has not been initialized will be `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Null and undefined can be treated in the same way

`if (typeof data === "undefined")` will return true if the data is undefined (or null), so

```
if (typeof data !== "undefined")
```

will return true if the data has been defined (so is not null), then you can check if it is an empty string,

```
if (data.length == 0)
```

will return true if the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a ReSharper error or is there something behind this ?

The error might be thrown because of a linter in resharper.

To check if the data is null || undefined || blank string, you could coherce the data value to a boolean (implicitly done by js):

```
if(!data) //implicit coercion
```

or do it explicitly:

```
if(!Boolean(data)){ //same as above
//if data is a falsy value (false, 0, null , undefined, NaN, '' or ""), run
}
```

You can check the list of truthy and falsy values [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)